# Need some clear code for template implementation

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on a C++ library with some template class and method (almost only templates). I wanted to split declaration and implementation for a more easy reading. But sometimes it become just insane:

```
template < typename T >
class Foo {

  template < typename U >
  class SubFoo {

  };

  template < typename U >
  SubFoo<U> bar();
};

template < typename T >
template < typename U >
Foo<T>::SubFoo<U> Foo<T>::bar() {}
```

And this is a really minimal example...
So if you have some alias to improve this, or any coding style guide.
I'm working with NeoVim, so if you know some plugins which can make life easier it'll be nice too.

Ps: I don't have any c++ restrictions.

---

In fact I forget that some basic stuff like macro exist in C++.

```
#define Class Foo<T>

template < typename T >
template < typename U >
Class::SubFoo<U> Class::bar() {}
```

Not really nice, but still better. Anyway to do it **without macro**?

Comment: So separating the implementation doesn't give you "more easy reading". The usual way to "solve" it is *not* to attempt this.

Comment: don't write in c++ if you want readable code :p. If you use neovim is hard to find a good auto format plugin.

Comment: But I really like the header which describe the class and the source file where you can found the implementation. I think that everything in the same file is a mess.

Comment: You don't have to write the templates line by line as you did, you can also write
template < typename T, typename U >

Comment: @Jan B yes I know, I just like to do the separation (I usually put one typename per line). The big deal is the line to implement the function.

Comment: The inability to split template definitions from their declarations is an age-old problem in C++. The only theoretical solution to it was the `export` keyword, but almost no compiler implemented it, it would not do what people expected anyway, and it has been removed from C++. Just live with it. The most important thing is that your library's **documentation** is easy to read, and of course the client code resulting from its usage.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I'm still wonder if there is no way to improve this code with using or whatever.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel: The only real improvement to it is re-merging the definition of `bar()` with its declaration. Other than that, it's hard to say, because with names like "foo" and "bar", it's always hard to theorise about readability.

Comment: @ChristianHackl It's sad but I'll do it so. Who know maybe someone will do something for that one day. Don't know if modules are going to change something to this.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel: With modules and concepts, maybe. By the way, you may find the following old article by Herb Sutter interesting, as it explains the pitfalls of `export`: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/sutters-mill-herb-sutter-export-restrict/184401563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if it's idea good enought, so I won't accept the answer for now.

Let's take a real case (a small, don't worry):

```
template < typename Object, bool Shared >
  template < ECS_INT Filter >
DefaultManager<Object, Shared>::iterator<Filter>  DefaultManager<Object, Shared>::begin() {

  unsigned int i;
  for (i = 0;
       !iterator<Filter>::is_Valid(m_pool[i].data);
       ++i);
  return std::move(iterator<Filter>(i));
}

template < typename Object, bool Shared >
  template < ECS_INT Filter >
DefaultManager<Object, Shared>::iterator<Filter>  DefaultManager<Object, Shared>::end() {

  unsigned int i;
  for (i = m_pool.size();
       !iterator<Filter>::is_Valid(m_pool[i].data);
       --i);
  return std::move(iterator<Filter>(i));
}
```

---

```
#define TEMPLATE_ARGS  typename Object, bool Shared
#define CLASS    DefaultManager<Object, Shared>
#define ITERATOR CLASS::iterator<Filter>

template < TEMPLATE_ARGS >
  template < ECS_INT Filter >
ITERATOR  CLASS::begin() {

  unsigned int i;
  for (i = 0;
       !ITERATOR::is_Valid(m_pool[i].data);
       ++i);
  return std::move(ITERATOR(i));
}

template < TEMPLATE_ARGS >
  template < ECS_INT Filter >
ITERATOR  CLASS::end() {

  unsigned int i;
  for (i = m_pool.size();
       !ITERATOR::is_Valid(m_pool[i].data);
       --i);
  return std::move(ITERATOR(i));
}
```

Now you'll say me that's will be a real problem to create so many macro in the program and I should at least and a namespace in the macro name. But with modules this won't be required, because macro won't be exported by default.

I think that's a little improvement, but maybe not a good one.

Answer (score 0):

> I really like the header which describe the class and the source file where you can found the implementation. I think that everything in the same file is a mess

Maybe you're right, when you say "that everything in the same file is a mess", but with **template** structs/classes it's really difficult to avoid.

The following it's a trivial example

Suppose you have three files

1) a header ("header.h") where is defined a template struct `foo` with a constructor that is defined but not implemented

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
 { 
   foo ();
 };
```

2) a cpp file ("a.cpp") whith a `main()` where a `foo<int>` variable is declared

```
#include "header.h"

int main ()
 {
   foo<int>  fi;
 }
```

3) a cpp file ("b.cpp") where the `foo` constructor is implemented

```
#include "header.h"

template <typename T>
foo<T>::foo ()
 { }
```

Nice, isn't it?

But when you compile (I use `clang++ -c -o a.o a.cpp` and `clang++ -c -o b.o b.cpp`) and link (`clang++ -o a.out a.o b.o`), you get an error in linking phase: undefined reference to `foo<int>::foo()`

Why?

It's because that compiling "b.cpp", the compiler doesn't know that in "a.cpp" its declared a `foo<int>` variable, so doesn't implement `foo<int>::foo()`.

Yes, you could explicitly say to the compiler that, compiling "b.cpp", it must implement what it's necessary for `foo<int>`, modifying "b.cpp" as follows

```
#include "header.h"

template <typename T>
foo<T>::foo ()
 { }

template struct foo<int>;
```

but when you want use a `foo<long>` in an different source file, you have to remember to update "b.cpp" accordingly.

This is a good solution (IMHO) only if you want control the exact set of types that `foo<T>` can implement.

Usually (IMHO) the best solution is to implement all of a template struct/class in the header and (IMHO, as usual) it's clearer implement it in the body of the struct/class

Comment: I know that don't worry. Split in several files it's just that I have a .tpp file which is include at the end of the template.hpp file, and out of the class. That's why I end with that kind of code. But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I shouldn't have said header and source file, but didn't know how to say something else.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel - sorry: I didn't know it's was clear for you :(

Comment: That's me who is sorry, because you take your time for this :(